# JQuery UI removeClass() animation not triggering chrome only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome

Hi folks of stackoverflow,

Edit: Here is a fiddle of the problem area, as requested.  Unfortunately, JSfiddle doesn't seem to do JQuery UI animations at all so it is not showing the problem.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/P6KYt/4/)

Edit 2:  I've prepared 2 gifs to illustrate the problem exactly.  Top gif is Chrome and the problem, FireFox is bottom and the desired look.  Notice how the chrome gif animates on hover, but when the class is removed, it snaps back without animation.

[Imgur to .gifs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8asx.jpg)

To clarify, addClass as it is in JQuery UI has an extra parameter that will animate css changes based on the time specified.  It works just fine for addClass(".hovered",300), but the same does not work for removeClass(".hovered",300).  The element just snaps back into place with no animations but only in Google Chrome.  It works as it should in FireFox.  Here is the code:

```
// Hover handler, add hovered class to menu elements
$(".menu").hover(
// If hovering
function()
 {
    $(this).addClass("hovered",300);
    currentHover = $(this).attr('id');

 },
 // If not hovering
 function()
 {
    currentHover = null;
 });

// Function for returning all un-flagged menu elements to default position
var animator = function()
{
    $(".menu").not("#"+currentHover).removeClass("hovered",300);
            $(".menu").animate();
};

// Sets interval for animator
   setInterval(animator, 200);
```

In case anyone is wondering, the additional `.animate()` function is to stop queued animations that happen when you rapidly hover over the menu elements.  The animator function is what removes the hovered class from elements that are not flagged as hovered, focused or the current element that is in the viewport.

Here is the CSS for the menu, and any parent elements that I thought were relevant:

```
html {
height: 4220px;
width: 100%;
background: url(space.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
font-size: 100%;
}

#menuWrapper {
font-size: 40px;
width:352px;
height:3935px;
position:absolute;
background-color:rgba(140,140,140,0.8);
}

#menu {
left: 35px;
height: 350px;
width: 200px;
text-align:left;
position:fixed;
color:#FFF;
padding:0;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari rule*/
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox*/
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE*/
user-select: none;

}

a.menu {    
font-family:Verdana,Verdana, sans-serif;
text-align:left;
position:absolute;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
color:#FFF;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 40px;

}

.hovered {
left: 95px;
}
```

And finally, the HTML:

```
<div id="menuWrapper">
        <div id="menu">
            <a href="#homeSection" id="home" class="menu" unselectable="on">Home</a> <br />
            <a href="#aboutSection" id="about" class="menu" unselectable="on">About</a> <br />
            <a href="#projectSection" id="project" class="menu" unselectable="on">Projects</a> <br />
            <a href="#contactSection" id="contact" class="menu" unselectable="on">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There have been bugs like this with JQuery UI and Chrome in the past, but I was only able to find "solved" or fixed bugs.  I also am using the latest version of JQuery and JQuery UI, as well as the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox to do my testing.  I greatly appreciate any help/advice.

Comment: Your javascript is invalid. you are not closing "hover" function.. and WHEN animator function is being called? can you post it in a fiddle?

Comment: Still broken in 2016. jQuery UI easing works on addClass but fails on removeClass in Chrome. Similar function/fail on toggleClass--adds work, removes don't. 

The underlying function works, but the remove happens instantly rather than easing.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `hovered` class from all elements first, then add to "hovered" element:

```
$(".menu").hover(function() {
    $('.menu').removeClass('hovered')
    $(this).addClass("hovered");
});
```

[see Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6KYt/1)